# How to implement Guided view in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I need to implement "Guided View" functionality like DC Comics or Marvel comics applications. I don't have an idea to start this functionality. any one can please suggest me on this. Below is the link for Guided view details [Guided View link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GoodUXInTheWildAComicBookGeekReturnsAfterTwentyYearsAwayToABraveNewDigitalWorld.aspx).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good start is to read something about ViewPager and Animations.

ViewPager - http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Animations - http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html

Hope it helps.